# How to acces gmap markers after map is generated?

Tags: 7, javascript, google-maps

I've got a problem with Google map markers and I don't find a way to solve it.

I've got a map page view generated with the [GMap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module where I show certain nodes. I've got also a view block that show some of the same nodes that appear in the map in an unformatted list. What I need is to relate the nodes on the list with their respective markers in the map (so hovering the list change the marker icon or vice versa).

I could relate the nodes with the markers since I've got the exact coordinates of the node which coincide with the marker coordinates (obviously). My problem is that I don't know how to get a list of the existing markers on the map.

From what I've read I should push the markers in an array when they're generated so later I can acces to the markers using the elements in the array, but I couldn't found where does gmap generate the markers. I've tried creating a global array and pushing the markers in the `gmap_marker.js` inside:

```
obj.bind('addmarker', function (marker) {
  // ... //
    mymarker.push(marker.marker);
}
```

but even I can see any result. I tried counting the markers that are generated  with something like `countmarkers += 1;` but the output is also 0.

Anyone has a clue on hou could I achieve this? Any advice would be appreciated.

> Edit:  Ok, I solved this problem.  It looks like what I did was fine
>   and the problem was in the timing of the process. I called:
>
> ```
> mymarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
>         //funciona OK
>         alert(marker.getPosition().lat() + ' - ' + marker.getPosition().lng());
>     });
> ```
>
> inside a `setTimeout(function(){});` with a 10ms delay. By increasing
>   the delay to 5000ms all the markers have enough time to be created and
>   I can finally access the markers array.

Comment: `mymarkersarray[] = marker;` is not valid javascript, start with that

Comment: sorry I wrote this without the code in front of me, It's actually something like: 'mymarkers.push(marker);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quote from the [Comparison of mapping modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704948):

> GMap is considered a legacy module.

So maybe you want to have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question was more related with the specific issue of acessing the marker js objects of the map. I'll take your answer as a reference for future projects (changing the mapping module would take too much time in the current project which is almost finished).

Comment: Merci Miquel for your feedback, and considering it for future projects. About your "*... current project ...*": ***There is never time to do it right, but always time to do it again***", right?

Comment: Off course you're right but that's something which is not in my hands. :)

Comment: Yet another way to look at it: first try to make it work with gmap (whatever it takes), trying to deliver what the customer asked for. After you succeeded, suggest the customer a recommended alternative "for the next version of the site" (which didn't make it in the prior version due to deadlines coming close) ...